# How to configure Azure Data Management gateway to not use internet to transfer data using Azure data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-vpn, azure-security

I am trying to use Azure Data factory to transfer data from On Premise database to Azure blob storage. I know data management gateway uses HTTPS to transfer data but We want to configure the connection in a way that Data management gateway doesn't use internet to transfer data from On premise database to azure blob.

```
1. Do we need to use Azure ExpressRoute to extend out Virtual Network to Azure Network?
2. Do we need to use Site to Site VPN to extend Azure Vnet to Our virtual network?
```

Will these approaches avoid using internet with Data Management Gateway?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want the data to go over public network, you can use :
1. Express Route - dedicated channel. 
2. VPN - the data still goes through public cloud but encrypted. Should require Virtual Network.

Most sources including Storage, Azure SQL DB support connectivity via Express route public peering. 
Second approach is more to transfer data on a box on azure or inside a VNET in Azure. Not many sources today can be added to VNET!

So I would suggest the 1st option.

If you extend your network by site-to-site VPN with Azure VNET, you can securely get the data to VNET. Then use mechanism to put data on to Azure Blob.